# How to make a simple DTR(daily time record) in python

Tags: python, input

Im starting to learn this language and our teacher gave us a program to make, and this the problem. "**Create a program that will simulate a Simple DTR (Daily Time Record) System. Your
program must allow the user to input an employee name and hours worked from Monday to
Saturday. It should also ask the user to input the hourly rate of the employee. Your program
must be able to display the total number of hours worked by the employee and the total gross
pay earned by the employee**". he didnt really taught us that much so i dont know what to do.

i can only do the simple input and display its name but other than that i can barely think of anything.

Comment: You should find a book or tutorial like e. g. the standard [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and learn from that.

Comment: Indeed, do some research, try to write some code, test it, then post it along with a more specific question if your code doesn't work or doesn't provide the intended result.